# Multi selection list view using MvxListView with MvvmCross

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross, mvxlistview

I have a MvxListView with multiselection mode. I want to toggle its clicked item color. If it is a listview then I can do it by code on view. But how can I do same task in MVVMCross ? Because MvxListView Itemclick is  bind on View Model and here we not get clicked item object not get. Please help

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `ValueConverter` and the plugin `MvvmCross.Plugin.Color` ( can be found in NuGet ).

The `ValueConverter` can translate a `Boolean` to a `Color` for example:

```
public class BlackOrBlueColorValueConverter : MvxColorValueConverter<bool>
{
    protected override MvxColor Convert(bool value, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value)
            return MvxColors.Black;
        else
            return MvxColors.Blue;
    }
}
```

Create a property `Selected` within the class that is bound to the `MvxListView`

```
private bool _selected
public bool Selected
{
    get
    {
        return _selected;
    }
    set { _selected = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => Selected); }
}
```

Bind the property in your `Axml`

```
local:MvxBind="BackgroundColor BlackOrBlueColor(Selected);"
```

On the `ItemClickCommand` set the property `Selected` to `false` or `true` and the color changes.

For more information about value converters have a look at [MvvmCross ValueConverters](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/value-converters)

Comment: In this line local:MvxBind="TextColor BlackOrBlueColor(IsMine);" What is IsMine here?

Comment: Oh whoops that is supposed to be `Selected` made an edit to the post and the TextColor is supposed to be BackgroundColor

Comment: Thank you. I will try it but I have doubt that it works only for single choice mode. Not works if my mvxlistview choice mode is multiple. What you think ?

Comment: This should work for multiple selection as long as you bind the property `Selected`. Just to make sure are you creating the `Selected` property in your `List<T>` or `ObservableCollection<T>` as `T.Selected`? If you create the property within the ViewModel this will not work. But if you add it to your collection of items it will work.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your help and suggestion. I will try and definitely back to you.